# How do I use a c:/ directory path in php5 using file_get_contents?

Tags: php

Hello I'm having problems getting my file_get_contents(); to return a string, if I use this function for a file on the actual web server it works fine but if that file which worked on the web server is now moved to my personal computer c:/ drive then file_get_contents(); does not work anymore.... I've tried adding a ini_set(); include path with no avail.

Bit flustered with the lack of absolute accurate documentation on php side unless I've missed something.

I've read the documentation here --> http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and here --> http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.set-include-path.php too.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","pass", "DB");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

$SQL_query = "SELECT text FROM table";

$query = mysqli_query($db, $SQL_query);

echo getcwd();

$file_path = "C:\folder\file.txt";

echo file_get_contents($file_path);

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $result["username"] . " ";

    if(strstr($file, $result["username"])) 
    {
        echo "Hello this is equal!";

    }else {
        echo"this is not equal!"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried $file_path = "c:/folder/file.txt"; as well with no avail.

Comment: I believe it has to be like so: "C:\Folder\File.txt"

Comment: Tried $file_path = "C:\folder\txt.txt"; nope didn't work. -_- any other help would be great right now , very agitated by this.

Comment: What about using the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant to account for differences in the environments.  http://www.php.net//manual/en/dir.constants.php

Comment: DIRECTORY_SEPEARTOR what is that some kind of constant how does that work ... , I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 2):

Since the backslash is the escape character, you are escaping the `f` character in that string. The result is `C:folderfile.txt`.

You have to double the backslash each time you want to use it (with another words, you have to escape the backslash with backslash):

```
$file_path = "C:\\folder\\file.txt";
```

chandlermania's suggestion is even better to use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant

```
$file_path = "C:" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "file.txt";
```

Comment: Or simply just use `/` instead of that fugly constant.

Comment: It's still not working you guys realize that the file.txt is actually on my pc not on the web server yes?... why is this not working.. --> $file = file_get_contents("C:\\folder\\file.txt");
the folder and text file are in my local disk c: drive. Going to try the directory seperator method now.

Comment: No, not relized, in this case you have to upload your file.

Comment: So you mean that everytime my users go to my site they will have to upload the id file to be able to log in is there a way to automate that so they don't have to do anything? I know it's possible. Without having to manually type in a password or username. "that's like newbstyle that is".

Comment: Why do you need to use a file to authenticate a user? Implement some kind of authentication (user/pass) to identify them.

Comment: Why should people need to authenticate after they have register themself into a database it should work automatically , I was trying to replicate a id card concept in php,  I know that it's possible just don't know how to go about it now since this solution is not providing correct results nor is fopen ... unless I have to manually read each line which I can do.

Comment: PHP is a `server side` script language. Your file is stored on the `cient's` computer. The server could not connect to the client's machine (unless some client side settings: some kind file sharing). Another way - if this functionality is really required - to write a browser plugin or do it with flash or java applet and grant access for the applet to the client's filesystem. (Personally I'll never accept grant that rights to any kind of applet)

Comment: So javascript is required then? Pred. Clarification allows me to setup my mind correctly in the right natural direction.

Comment: You can start here: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/ Please note, that the user should select the file manually. This is a HTML5 feature and I'm not sure which browsers support it.